# average of five valuesin javascript

Tags: javascript, average

I work for a charter school and I'm just learning my way around javascript.  I've got some code written by the person who formerly filled my position and it seems to me that it should work, but it doesn't.

This is what I have in the custom HTML page in my SIS:

```
GED Status: <script language="Javascript">gedCheck('~(ELC_tspp_GED_read_score)','~ (ELC_tspp_GED_wri_score)','~(ELC_tspp_math_GED_score)','~(ELC_science_state_exam_score)','~(soc_sci_state_exam_score)')</script>
```

That seems to be retrieving the values from the various DB fields correctly, as the javascript routine is evaluating each value to ensure it's at least 410.  But that's as far as it goes...

Here's the javascript routine code:

```
function gedCheck(read,wri,math,sci,soc) {

if( read < 0 && read > 1000 )
    read = 0;
if( wri < 0 && wri > 1000 )
    wri = 0;
if( math < 0 && math > 1000 )
    math = 0;
if( sci < 0 && read > 1000 )
    read = 0;
if( soc < 0 && soc > 1000 )
    soc = 0;        

if ( (read >= 410) && (wri >= 410) && (math >= 410) && (sci >= 410) && (soc >= 410) ) {
    if( read+wri+math+sci+soc >= 2250 )
        document.write( "PASSED" )
}
else
    document.write( "NOT PASSED" )
}
```

It is supposed to be checking that every score in the GED tests is at least 410, and that the sum of all scores should be at least 2250.  However, it's not getting as far as the last part.  It's returning "PASSED" if all the scores are over 410.

I tried this but it, also, doesn't work.

```
function gedCheck(read,wri,math,sci,soc) {

if( read < 0 && read > 1000 )
    read = 0;
if( wri < 0 && wri > 1000 )
    wri = 0;
if( math < 0 && math > 1000 )
    math = 0;
if( sci < 0 && read > 1000 )
    read = 0;
if( soc < 0 && soc > 1000 )
    soc = 0;        

if ( (read >= 410) && (wri >= 410) && (math >= 410) && (sci >= 410) && (soc >= 410) )   {
    if( read+wri+math+sci+soc/5 >= 450 )
        document.write( "PASSED" )
}
else
    document.write( "NOT PASSED" )
}
```

Would somebody please help me work this out so it either averages all 5 numbers and returns "PASSED" only if the average is 450, OR simply adds all 5 numbers and returns "PASSED" only if the total sum is 2250 or greater?

Comment: if (read < 0 && read > 1000): 

As you said you're just learning, a tip is that this will never, ever be the case. What you're asking here is like, "Is read less than 0, but also more than 1000, at the exact same time?" || should be used instead of &&. && means "If this AND this", || means "If this, or this". || in your case changes it to, "If read is less than zero, or it's more than 1000, do this", which is possible, as no number in Math is both less than zero, but more than 1000.

Note: | is shift + \ key, and is called a "Pipe"

Comment: I think that's why he did it - maybe he just wanted to make sure every value got set to 0 to start off with?  Or does a person never do that?

Comment: In that, it'll never set it to zero as that's the code that follows, and since it'll never be both less than 0 and greater than 1000, it'll never, ever set it to 0. It makes sense if he wanted to make it zero if either of those conditions is met (0 Minimum, 1000 score is max I assume), but that's why you'd use an OR (||) Operator, not an AND (&&). Code after an if, like read = 0, only executes if the if block returns true. Read < 0 && Read > 1000 will never return true, therefore, it'll never set read to 0. Same with the others.

Comment: I see - thank you!  Ok, so essentially all that code was non-working anyway.  So where should I look to find where he actually named everything as he has?  I cannot seem to figure out how you tie the value in the database field to the actual name he is using...

Comment: function gedCheck(read,wri,math,sci,soc). See the order of things, and the comma? Each time a comma is used, that means "Hey, I'm done with this one, I'll start the next". Match the commas and the words in these two things, and it should make a bit of sense.

`function gedCheck(read,wri,math,sci,soc)`   
and
`gedCheck('~(ELC_tspp_GED_read_score)','~ (ELC_tspp_GED_wri_score)','~(ELC_tspp_math_GED_score)','~(ELC_science_state_exam_score)','~(soc_sci_state_exam_score)')`

Comment: *facepalm*  WOW!  How did I miss that!  LOL - well, that's a huge lesson right there.  Thanks SO MUCH!

Comment: You're just learning you said, so don't worry about it. It takes a while to catch on to some things like that if you're just getting into it all.

Comment: I want very much to vote up the answers that helped me learn, but I don't have enough reputation points yet, apparently.  Please know how much I appreciate your answer - I truly mean it!  Yours and several others have helped me grasp some programming concepts I didn't understand, and I'm genuinely appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average, you'll want to do this:

```
(((read + wri + math + sci + soc) / 5) > 450)
```

The parenthesis around the addition ensures that you divide the sum of all scores by 5. The way that you have it now, you are only dividing the `soc` score by 5.

Edit (Rewriting the entire method):

```
function gedCheck(read, wri, math, sci, soc) {
// As was said before, these should all be ORs
// If the score is less than 0, OR greater than 1000
if( read < 0 || read > 1000 ) {
    read = 0;
}
if( wri < 0 || wri > 1000 ) { // I prefer to put the braces around all if/else statements just for absolute clarity
    wri = 0;
}
if( math < 0 || math > 1000 ) {
    math = 0;
}
if( sci < 0 || read > 1000 ) {
    read = 0;
}
if( soc < 0 || soc > 1000 ) {
    soc = 0;        
}

if ( read >= 410 && // Doing this will only pass the student
     wri >= 410  && // if ALL of the conditions are met.
     math >= 410 && 
     sci >= 410  && 
     soc >= 410  &&
     (    (read + wri + math + sci + soc) >= 2250 || // Separated more for clarity
          ((read + wri + math + sci + soc) / 5) > 450) ) { 
    // Either all scores total over 2250
    // Or the average of all 5 are over 450 to pass                
        document.write( "PASSED" )
}
else
    document.write( "NOT PASSED" )
}
```

Comment: Oh!  Thank you!  Still not getting anything to work, but I can see exactly what you're saying...

Comment: I've reworked your entire function for you. Hopefully this will help you out some more. I've added notations throughout explaining why I've done certain things, and how it should help give you what you're looking for. If you have other questions, or it's still not working correctly, let me know.

Comment: You've all be absolutely wonderful.  I can only think at this point that perhaps the database is not returning the values of these fields as an integer.  Is that possible?

Comment: It's always possible. At the very beginning of the function, set each like this: `read = parseInt(read)`. See if that helps. Otherwise, see if there's a way that you can step through your code so you can see what each one is giving you.

Comment: Yes, that's one thing I have been trying to do.  I do see it correctly displaying the characters, but I'm not sure they're actual numbers that Javascript can work with.  Trying the parseInt now...

Comment: That was it!  With the parseInt setting on each variable, it now calculates correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with JavaScript is that it doesn't care what type of variable it is supposed to be (that's why everything is a `var` instead of int/string/etc). What was happening then was it was trying to compare everything as strings then with your math comparisons. JS defaults to everything as a string unless you explicitly send it as such.

Comment: So your method was getting populated with strings then, and trying to compare them as such. If you were to create a variable like `var read = 15;`, it will save it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if ((read >= 410) && 
    (wri  >= 410) && 
    (math >= 410) && 
    (sci  >= 410) && 
    (soc  >= 410) &&
    (read+wri+math+sci+soc >= 2250)) {    

    document.write( "PASSED" )
} else {

    document.write( "NOT PASSED" )
}
```

Comment: I actually used this code after learning the parseInt setting and it worked perfectly - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function gedCheck(read, wri, math, sci, soc) {

    if( read < 0 || read > 1000 )
        read = 0;

    if( wri < 0 || wri > 1000 )
        wri = 0;

    if( math < 0 && math > 1000 )
        math = 0;

    if( sci < 0 && read > 1000 )
        read = 0;

    if( soc < 0 && soc > 1000 )
        soc = 0;

    var total = read + wri + math + sci + soc;

    if (read >= 410 && wri >= 410 && math >= 410 && sci >= 410 && soc >= 410 && total >= 2250)   {   
        document.write("PASSED");
    } else {
        document.write("NOT PASSED");
    }
}
```

That whole first section was impossible code. It was checking to see if a number was BOTH less than zero and greater than 1000. Obviously impossible, so I changed it to use OR.

I also created a total variable, which you can check in the same way as everything else.

Comment: Hi Jordon, this is what I was trying to figure out - how to set the sum of all five scores as a variable.  Thanks for showing me that.  I don't have a positive result yet, but it may be just that I have to flush the custom page cache in the SIS software... stand by...

Comment: I want very much to vote up the answers that helped me learn, but I don't have enough reputation points yet, apparently.  Please know how much I appreciate your answer - I truly mean it!  Yours and several others have helped me grasp some programming concepts I didn't understand, and I'm genuinely appreciative.

Comment: I have upvoted your question. You just need a few more reputation to be able to vote. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using an array here will help you reduce the amount of duplicated code

```
function gedCheck(read, wri, math, sci, soc) {
   var subjects, totalScore, averageScore;

   subjects = [read, wri, math, sci, soc];
   totalScore = 0;
   averageScore = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
       if (subjects[i] < 0 || subjects[i] > 1000) {
           subjects[i] = 0;
       }
       totalScore += subjects[i];
   };

   averageScore = totalScore / subjects.length;

   if (averageScore >= 450 || totalScore >= 2250) {
       document.write("PASSED");
   } else {
       document.write("NOT PASSED");
   }
}
```

The first loop iterates through each subject and sets it to zero if necessary, and then adds it to the total score variable.

Then the total score is averaged by the number of subjects.

Then if the average score is equal to or greater than 450, or equal to or greater than 2250, it passes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how that loop works - there just has to be something else wrong somewhere in this code.  Nothing I do works, and it has been long enough that the cache should have cleared.  I'm going to try to find where he named each subject as it is in the code.  *sigh*

Comment: I want very much to vote up the answers that helped me learn, but I don't have enough reputation points yet, apparently.  Please know how much I appreciate your answer - I truly mean it!  Yours and several others have helped me grasp some programming concepts I didn't understand, and I'm genuinely appreciative.